# Removing "Save & New Task' , 'Save & New Event' button

Tags: button

Can we rempove a button from the edit page layout of standard page. with out overriding.i need to remove the button fully.How can it be possible.

[image]

above attached was the edit layout of the standard task.now i want to remove the **save&Newtask button** and **save&newEvent buttons** from this edit layout.

How can i achieve this?Guide me in achieving this.

Comment: Which button ?Add more info to description please

Comment: hi mohith i had shared the details pls tell how to achieve this.

Comment: As this is standard Salesforce I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: see https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gvWnAAI

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible actually.
If I understand your question your requirement is to prevent users from creating new tasks and event from the task page.

You can go to the desired profile ->System Permissions->Disable Edit Events check box(or Disable Edit Tasks check box)->Save